# oracle keep_first unit test

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing

When running a maven test, I get an error back:

Failed tests:
    `getUsageReportDataTest(com.lanyon.dao.gcorp.tmcusagereport.TestTMCUsageReportDAOImpl): PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select distinct channelid, first_value(active) over (partition by channelid order by active) as a from exchange.accountautoprocess ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FIRST_VALUE`

My command line is:
    mvn -Dtest=TestTMCUsageReportDAOImpl -DfailIfNoTests=false test

The sql is:
    select distinct channelid, first_value(active) over (partition by channelid 
    order by active) as a from aap

It's executed by jdbctemplate:

```
List<String[]> result = namedJdbcTemplate.query(sql, paramSource, new 
    RowMapper<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public String[] mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws 
                SQLException {
                return new String[]{resultSet.getString("channelid"), 
                    resultSet.getString("a")};
            }
});
```

The maven for my jdbc driver is:
    `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>`

Does anybody know why the unit test would be unable to execute first_value, when I'm able to execute it in the database just fine? Even running the code normally succeeds. It's just the unit test that can't execute that sql.

Comment: I do not know nothing about maven but did you connect to Oracle from maven to execute this query? Just a thought. I do not see any connection string in your code.

Comment: This is a unit test. I would not connect to any database to execute this.